# Enable Web sharing in mac sierra and access the server from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, server, webrick, superuser

I a running rails app in my local in port 3000. I can access the app by hitting the local host or http://10.55.18.22:3000/ but i am not able to access the site from other devices(in the same network).

How can i make this accessible from outside my mac machine also?

Kindly note that web sharing option is not available in mac sierra.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Local = Your local machine. I would imagine basic security reasons prevent other devices from accessing your mac sessions.

Comment: Yes. I too think so. OMG, i don't know why am getting downvotes.

Comment: Dunno why the downvotes... this is a tricky question and plausibly introduces glaring security holes to your system, which might be why. In any case - have you looked into web hosting eg heroku? (there are plenty of others too). Most people don't host on their own laptop, but will host somewhere else.